# How to optimise this dijkstra's algoritjm?

Tags: python, pandas, dijkstra, path-finding

I am trying to find the shortest path between 2 points, where the edges are given by 'neighbours', as lists, in the json file

```
with open(r'C:\ads\game_board_2019.geojson') as f:
    adjacency = json.load(f)
adjacency = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    [i['properties'] for i in adjacency['features']], ).set_index('id', drop=True)
```

(the pandas dataframe looks like this)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSv5N.png)

Below is my current algorithm

```
start = np.random.choice(adjacency.index)
end = np.random.choice(adjacency.index)

# vertices = np.array(adjacency.index, dtype='<U7')
vertices = list(adjacency.index)
n_vertices = len(vertices)
adjacency['label'] = np.inf
adjacency['path'] = [np.empty(0, dtype='<U7')]*n_vertices
adjacency.at[start, 'label'] = 0

for i in range(n_vertices):
    cur = adjacency.loc[vertices].label.idxmin()
    if (cur == end):
        break
    vertices.remove(cur)
    neighbourhood = adjacency.loc[cur].neighbours
    for j in np.intersect1d(neighbourhood, vertices):
        new_weight = adjacency.at[cur, 'label'] + 1
        if adjacency.at[j, 'label'] > new_weight:
            adjacency.at[j, 'label'] = new_weight  # weight == 1 for all edges
            adjacency.at[j, 'path'] = np.append(adjacency.at[cur, 'path'], cur)
path = adjacency.loc[end].path
```

This algorithm does work but is way too inefficient (takes around 15 second to run, when the desired amount of time is around 0.5 seconds). Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

You need a different data structure. Dijkstra's Algorithm traditionally uses a heap or priority queue to ensure that you always have fast access to which unexplored node has the shortest distance. In your algorithm, `.idxmin()` loops over the entire dataframe, so you need a data structure that makes that call fast instead of creating an inner loop.

Comment: FWIW, the Python standard library provides a heap/priority queue implementation as [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html).